# How to add commission to products at bluesnap using forms

Tags: bluesnap

I'm integrating BlueSnap with my website,
Is it possible to add the commission parameters "commissionPercent" to my form request like this:

https://www.bluesnap.com/jsp/checkout.jsp?currency=EUR&developerId=XXXXXXX&commissionPercent=30&vendorId=XXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot add commission parameters "commissionPercent" to your form request